# SQL Server - Return the decimal value of a hexadecimal registry value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve a value from the registry and store its INT value.  The registry entry is DWORD and is in Hexadecimal format, however when retrieving the value using xp_regread it returns the hexadecimal value, and I need this in decimal.....any help?

Reg Key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ShortCuts\General]
"Appointment Interval"=dword:0000000f
```

The decimal value of the above key should be 15

Code used to return/store the value:

```
    DECLARE @Interval INT

DECLARE @temp_table TABLE (Value nvarchar(500), Data nvarchar(500))
INSERT INTO @temp_table EXEC master.sys.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Shortcuts\General', 'Appointment Interval'
SELECT @Interval = Data FROM @temp_table
```

Returning the variable @Interval currently returns 5

Comment: In what universe does `00000005`, interpreted as either hex or decimal mean 15?

Comment: Apologies, was a typo...have updated

Comment: The code you've shown (adjusting to a random registry value I could find on my machine that had a DWORD value) correctly returns the same value as in the registry. Are you sure that it's not some later code that's doing something incorrect?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the typo I had in the original question was in my code, and was giving the wrong result.  Thanks for your help...sometimes is all we need is a second pair of eyes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can start out by rather declaring the Data column in your @temp_table as a VARBINARY(8) as this will represent the hex value. Next when assigning the Data field to the @Interval variable convert it to INT as so:

CONVERT(INT, Data)

Hope this helps.